# crossing number and thickness of a simple graph $G$

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

> **Crossing number$($cr$)$**: The crossing number of a simple graph is the minimum number of crossings that can occur when this graph is drawn in the plane where no three arcs representing edges are permitted to cross at the same point. For an undirected simple graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and $e$ edges such that $e > 7n$ the crossing number is always at least $$cr(G)\geq \frac{e^3}{29n^2}$$

$(1)$ I was wondering is there exist any upper bound in general$?$ [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_(graph_theory)#Special_cases) is a upper bound for the crossing number of the complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$. I need a proof of that result.$($if possible than provide a simple's one$)$

> **Thickness**: The thickness of a simple graph G is the smallest number of
>   planar subgraphs of G that have G as their union.

$(2)$ I was wondering is there any relation between these two number$?$
I asked the same question at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3442581/565609) and get suggested to ask it here.

Comment: you can find details on the crossing number of $K_n$ in e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.3665v2

Comment: I will definitely look your given resource @DimaPasechnik

Comment: basically, for $K_n$ there are explicit drawings known, which provide you an upper bound on the  crossing number. The lower bound is still conjectural.

Comment: Perhaps the world’s expert on crossing numbers is Gelasio Salazar ... google him, all his papers (a ton of groundbreaking results) are (were) available on his university website

Comment: the one I linked is one of Gelasio’s papers :)

Comment: there is of course a trivial upper bound - assume that every edge intersects the others in a rectilinear drawing, getting $e\choose 2$ crossings, at most.